# Topological vector spaces in direct sum.

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, representation-theory, lie-groups, topological-vector-spaces

This question has emerged as an offshoot of a bigger topic [discussed here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4340895/two-definitions-of-complete-algebraic-reducibility-are-equivalent-by-zorns-lemm).
All linear vector spaces are over $\mathbb C$, and TVS is standing for *Topological Vector Space*.

DEFINITION

TVS subspaces $\left\{{\mathbb{V}}_i\subseteq{\mathbb{V}}:\;i\in {\cal{I}}\right\}$ of a TVS space ${\mathbb{V}}$ are *in direct sum* if the subspace they span
(1) is TVS, i.e. is closed;
(2) is their direct sum $\oplus  {\mathbb{V}}_{{j}}\,$:
$$
   {\mathbb{V}}_i \cap \left(
 \oplus 
   {\mathbb{V}}_{\textstyle{_j}}   \right)_{    \stackrel{}{\stackrel{_{j\in\cal I}}{\textstyle {_{j\neq i}}}}   }\,=\,\{\vec{0}\}  \quad\mbox{for}\;\forall\; i\in {\cal{I}}\;\;;
$$
The latter item implies that any family of vectors $\left\{ v_i:\;v_i\in{\mathbb{V}}_i,\;i\in {\cal{I}} \right\}$, which are zero for all but finitely many values of $i$, is linearly independent.
$\,$

In a TVS space $\mathbb V$, consider a closed TVS subspace ${\mathbb{W}}\subset\mathbb V$ and the set $\cal D$ of all closed TVS subspaces in direct sum with $\mathbb W$:
$$
{\cal D}\,=\,\left\{ {\mathbb{U}}:\;\;\;{\mathbb{U}}\subset{\mathbb{V}}\,,\;\;\;
{\mathbb{U}}\;\mbox{closed}\,,
  \;\;\;{\mathbb{U}}\cap{\mathbb{W}}=\vec{ 0}   \right\}\;\,.
$$
The set $\cal D$ is partially ordered by inclusion. For an infinite chain ${\cal C}\subset\cal D$, the increasing union $\bigcup_{\cal C}\mathbb U$ is not necessarily closed. Denote its closure with overbar:
$$
\tilde{\mathbb{U}}_{\cal C}\equiv\overline{\bigcup_{\cal C}\mathbb U}\,\;.
$$

QUESTION 1.

While the union $\bigcup_{\cal C}\mathbb U$ is certainly in direct sum with $\mathbb W$, will this be true for its closure $\tilde{\mathbb{U}}_{\cal C}\,$?

QUESTION 2.

Suppose that a topological representation $A(G)$ of a group $G$ is acting in $\mathbb V$, and assume that all our spaces $\mathbb W$ and $\mathbb U$ are not only closed but also invariant, i.e. contain topological subrepresentations of $A(G)$.

While the union $\bigcup_{\cal C}\mathbb U$ is invariant, will its closure $\tilde{\mathbb{U}}_{\cal C}$ be invariant also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No, let $V=\ell^2(\Bbb N)$, let $W$ be the span of the vector $(2^{-n})_{n\in\Bbb N}$ and let $U_k$ denote the space of sequences for which only the first $k$ terms are permitted to be non-zero. Clearly $U_k\cap W=0$ and $U_k$ is a chain, but $\overline{\bigcup_k U_k}=\ell^2(\Bbb N)$.
2. If the representation is *continuous* in the usual sense, ie the map
   $$G\times V\to V$$
   is a continous map, then the closure of an invariant subspace is also invariant. To see this: if $x_\alpha$ is a net in $U$ converging to a point in $\overline{U}$ then $g(\lim_\alpha x_\alpha)=\lim_{\alpha} g(x_\alpha)\in \overline U$.

Comment: Dear @s.harp , (1) Could you please explain to me the meaning of the notation $(2^{-n})_{n\in \mathbb N}~$? (2) I understand that a net is a generalisation of the notion of sequence, from a natural-numbers domain to a directed-set domain. When you are saying that $\,g(\lim_\alpha x_\alpha)=\lim_{\alpha} g(x_\alpha)\in \overline U\,$, do you imply that this is a generic property of nets, or is this due to the continuity of $G\times V\rightarrow V\;$? On this particular occasion, is it critical that $x_\alpha$ is a net, and not just a sequence?

Comment: (1) $\ell^2(\Bbb N)$ is commonly defined as the space of square summable sequences, $(2^{-n})_{n\in\Bbb N}$ then refers to the sequence that takes value $2^{-n}$ in the $n$th place. (2) Using nets is a convenient way to transfer arguments that use sequences to spaces that are not necessarily sequential. Because $g$ is a continuous map you have that the limit can be pulled out, because $U$ is invariant you have that $g(x_\alpha)\in U$ for all $\alpha$ and then, since the limit of a net in $U$ lies in $\overline U$, you get taht the limit is in $\overline U$.

Comment: The reason one has to use a net and not a sequence is that for a general topological space the closure of a set $U$ is *not* necessarily the set of all limits that arise from sequences in U. What you do have is that the closure is the set of all limits that arise from nets in $U$. If a topological space has the property $\overline U=$"sequential closure of U" for all sets $U$, then the space is called "sequential". Metric spaces for example are sequential. But there are topological vectorspaces that are not sequential (weak topology of an infinite dimensional Banach space is never sequential)

Comment: many thanks! A lot of food for thought.